# Cannot connect to domain error: The format of specified network name is invalid

Tags: active-directory, windows-sbs-2003

I cannot connect clients to sbs2003 domain because of this error: The format of specified network name is invalid.

Before that there is a prompt for a login and password, so the server is found. I can't also view the server resources via \ \ servername or \ \ ServerIP because it can not find the path. I can not add the computer account by servername/ConnectComputer because after entering the login and password  I can wait forever.

Clients can browse the web without any problems with the DNS server address - sbs2003.

nslookup servername gets the correct server name and the correct IP address. Pings to the server works without a problem.

Gateway / router / firewall for the network is debian, also DHCP Server. The topology is as follows:

modem - debian - lan where there are clients and the server SBS2003

Client gets the following configuration from DHCP server:

```
Connection-specific DNS Suffix: domain_name
IP Address: 192.168.20.100
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 192.168.20.1 - network interface on Debian
DHCP Server: 192.168.20.1
DNS Servers: 192.168.20.2 - SBS2003 server address
Primary WINS Server: 192.168.20.2
```

For the SBS:

dhcp service uninstalled

One interface

Interface configuration:

```
IP Address: 192.168.20.2
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 192.168.20.1
DNS server: 192.168.20.2
WINS Server: 192.168.20.2
```

DNS configuration:

forward here where I have entered OpenDNS DNS addresses

is set to listen on all IP addresses

So once again the internet works without a problem, client gets addressing from a DHCP server, on the client does not work server shares or connecting to a domain. Somebody help me because I no longer have the strength to go further.

Comment: You state: "I cannot connect clients to sbs2003 domain... Before that there is a prompt for a login and password, so the server is found." If the client is not connected to the domain, the prompt for a login and password would be for local accounts, not domain accounts, so I'm not sure why you see this as proof the "server is found".

Answer (score 0):

Host names are not allowed underscores... Or is the underscore just for demonstration purposes? If not I am not entirely sure how you managed to set up your SBS domain with an underscore but be prepared to bin your SBS build and do it with a standard domain name. Also try choosing a meaningful domain name.

Comment: This is just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: What is the domain name you're trying to enter? As it's the cause of the error you'll have to include it in your question to get an answer.

Comment: and is the dns suffix domain_name or domain_name.tld? It should be the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions I found that you might try:

- It may likely be that SID of the computer is already on the domain.
- To solved this problem, first rename the computer that's giving the error message.
- Restart the Computer and than add it back on the domain

The other:

- When I put in the full dns name "headquarters.rsa.local" I got this message. Once I just put in "headquarters" as the domain, it worked fine and let me join the domain.